# set and group by in the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Can I combine a 'set' with a 'group by'?

```
Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4
30       15        3 Sep
20       2         2 Sep
```

After updating:

```
Column1   Column2   Column3    Column4
30        15        3 Sep      30/50+15/17
20        2         2 Sep      20/50+2/17
```

I'm grouping the data by the entire September to calculate the sums: 50 and 17
And use this to update Column4 in the same query.

Thanks!

Comment: You're not updating but selecting.

Comment: I'm updating from NULL initially to these two values: 30/50+15/17 and 20/50+2/17

Answer (score 1):

As a select, you can do this in SQL Server using the window functions:

```
select column1, column2, column3,
       (column1/(sum(1.0*column1) over ()) +
        column2/(sum(1.0*column2) over ()))
from t
```

I included the "1.0*", because SQL Server does integer division.  You probably want floating point division for this.